# .NET Add constrained Generic type to List

Tags: .net, generics

I have constrained generic method and generic list of specified type. Is it somehow possible to add this constrained item to the list?

```
class Test
{ 
    private static Test _instance;
    private List<QueueItem<IData>> queue;

    public static void Enqueue<T>(QueueItem<T> i) where T : IData, new()
    {
        _instance.queue.Add(i); //Fails on compilation
    }
    //...some other code...
}
```

The other classes are:

```
public class IData
{
    public IData() { }
}

class QueueItem<T> where T : IData, new()
{
    public SomeUnchangableClass<T> Data {get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have to keep constraint **IData, new()** because the rest of the code. But I don't know why I am not able to add this item to the generic list since constraint is on the same class.

Comment: This may be of some insight for you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/

Answer (score 0):

It compiles if you add:

```
class QueueDataItem : QueueItem<IData> {}
```

and change `Test` to

```
class Test
{
    private static Test _instance;
    private List<QueueDataItem> queue;

    public static void Enqueue(QueueDataItem i) 
    {
        _instance.queue.Add(i); //Fails on compilation
    }
    //...some other code...
}
```